# Python JSON multiple API requests

Tags: python, json

I am trying to make multiple requests to an API and compile all the responses and convert the data to a dataframe. I am having trouble with creating the dataframe with the JSON filesalthough it does gather the data I need. I am left with an empty dataframe. If I remove the df.append I get the last request in the format I would like. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have never worked with an API.

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

ID = ['H-IE0000750506','H-IE0000007080','H-IE0001665294']
df1 = pd.DataFrame()


headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}

for x in ID:

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'paramX': x,})

    try:
        conn =http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.someAPI.com')
        conn.request('GET','/Company/Get?%s' % params, '{body}',headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        data = json.loads(data)
        df = pd.json_normalize(data['Result'])
        df1 = pd.append(df1,df)
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print('[Errno{0}] {1}'.format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Comment: But in your code you're not converting the data to a dataframe at all. Please add the code that is not working and specify how the dataframe should look

Comment: I think the issue is that the list does not create a valid json file so I cannot work with it as json data and convert to dataframe but I assume my API request will need to be changed in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in ID:

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    
        'HitHorizonsId': x,
    })

    try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.hithorizons.com')
        conn.request('GET','/Company/Get?%s' % params, '{body}', headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        data = json.loads(data)
        df = pd.json_normalize(data['Result'])
    except Exception as e:
        print('error')
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,df])
```